# Which database can be used with Xcode and at the same time be populated through a website?

Tags: ios, iphone, database, xcode

We are trying to create an iPhone application that will automatically receive data from a database. Which is a database that will work with Xcode. Our goal is that users can go to our website and input information. That data will be recorded to a database. Once the user downloads our app, the info should then be retrieved from the database and included in the app. We are wondering what database is suitable. It must be able to receive information from a website AND submit it to an application.

Answer (score 3):

You're unlikely to find a iOS "aware" database that can automatically sync content over the internet.

However, you can of course obtain the data over the internet yourself and then insert it into the local database on the device, in which case the popular (and supported out of the box) [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) would seem like an obvious choice.

As @Deepak also suggests, you could use [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) which is a (sort-of, ish) ORM that can automatically use SQLite as it's underlying storage mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that most people use in this case is to use an RDBMS like MySQL and build a web-service layer on top of the database for the entities that your iPhone app is interested in.

This way, when a user goes to the web-app, they can add the data that you allow them to add there, and later on they can access the same data from the iPhone app via the web-service layer also.

Answer (score 1):

Couchbase's new iOS-Couchbase framework is in beta right now - all the functionality of Apache CouchDB on your favourite developer platform - at https://github.com/couchbaselabs/iOS-Couchbase. the iOS release is new but we're looking for it to go places!

Its awesome sync abilities would allow you to pull down any relevant content from your website via HTTP/JSON, or further formats using shows and lists if needed. Pushing data the other way is just as easy. Sync can be continuous, or on demand, bidirectional or one way.

Take a look at some of the Couch App frameworks (not for iOS but for your website)

- http://techzone.couchbase.com/community/articles/couchdb/recipes
- http://www.mail-archive.com/user@couchdb.apache.org/msg13928.html lots of comments on this thread

A+
Dave